# Passing longint instead of int to mvc action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have controller with action which has int parameter with default 1 `public ActionResult Test(int p=1)`. If I call this method with long number for example 1000000000000 it works and p=1. I need return not found result. How to implement it? It really confused me..

Comment: Ok, nice:) Could you please answer not in comment to allow mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you provided a default value, the default value will be used if a valid value is not provided. If you require that `p` is valid to enter your method, don't provide a default value.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult Test(long p=1) {}
```

That should work for you if you need to handle long integers sent to your Action.